# How to Set Condition for MetaDescription in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, xml, php-7

I am trying to set a meta description dynamically for Magento 2 categories as default rules. And I did manage to do it, here is my code.

```
public function execute(
\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
) {
$category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
//$metaTitle = $category->getName() ." - xxx.club";
$metaDesc = "Place order for " .$category->getName() . " with us and get huge sales and discount!";
if ($category instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category) {
    //$oldMetaTitle = $category->getMetaTitle();
    $oldMetaDesc = $category->getMetaDesc();
    //$category->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
    $category->setMetaDescription($metaDesc);
}
}
```

I am trying to find a way to add a check so that observer check first if this page has meta description set in backend categories, then it should skip adding meta description, but add if there is no meta description tag on the page.

Comment: You can use if condition `if($category->getMetaDescription() == ''){ $category->setMetaDescription($metaDesc); }`

Comment: post it as answer man, so i accept it, it helped solve problem quickly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the category already has meta description and if not, set it with your custom text.

```
if($category->getMetaDescription() == '') { 
    $category->setMetaDescription($metaDesc);
}
```